# How to terminate a long running postgres query (in plv8 extension)?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, cpu-usage, pgadmin-4, plv8

I have executed a plv8 function on pgadmin 4, that uses nested for loops and some array functions.

This query was stopped using pgadmin cancel query (stop) button in GUI.

24 hours later,  This query still shows up as active and running.

I have Tried, pg_cancel_backend and pg_terminate_backend, but seems to have no impact.
Tried pg_ctl kill (TERM/ABRT/INT)command, but pid is not found.

However, AWS performance insights dashboard shows up, the query using 25-30% of CPU.

If you guys could suggest alternate ways, to terminate this query, That'd be really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: The remedies you tried are correct, so you must have done something wrong. Include details, show `pg_stat_activity` and quote the commands you used.

Comment: It seems like an extension based query, in this case PLV8 wasnt detecting the interrupt by pg_backend_kill or terminate backend,
Hence , the only option was to restart the server. and the query stopped.

Comment: That's a bug in PL/v8 that you should report.